# What is the meaning of localizing a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I was reading the manual of a plugin [here](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) and at one point it was written:

> External plugins like the jQuery UI datepicker have to be localized separately in their own way

What does that mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization

Comment: localization, for date format depending user culture, e.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization is a broad topic and covers many areas such as writing direction, character encoding, currency, time zones and many many more. But here the sentence is referring to the date picker feature of jQuery and it means if you are developing an app for Chinese audiences or any other culture that uses different kind of calendar you have to change the datepicker yourself and this plugin doesn't do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Localization involves taking source content and making it relavant for a local market - this includes translation, number formatting (1,000 vs 1.000), date formatting (03/18/2014 vs 18/03/2014), calendar display (Sunday - Saturday vs. Monday - Sunday), currency, and really anything that would make the content most applicable to a local market.